# Notification localization is not working in iOS 10

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios10

I'm trying to localize my notification title and body with `title-loc-key` and `loc-key`. It's working in iOS 9 correctly but not in iOS 10. Here is my notification payload:

```
"aps": {
    "badge": 1,
    "alert": {
        "loc-key": "localized-body-key",
        "title-loc-key": "localized-title-key"
    }
}
```

It directly takes localized string according to keys from `Localizable.strings` file in iOS 9. But in iOS 10 it just shows the keys in notification.

Does anyone have an idea or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add localized strings for all languages. This was the reason why it was showing only keys not localized strings.